# How to copy a string to clipboard while preserving its formatting in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building an app where the user is able to format text. I want to give them the ability to copy and paste that formatted text while preserving the formatting.

**Synfusion RTE control has this functionality.
[image]**

I'm using the Xamarin Essentials clipboard to copy to clipboard.

```
await Clipboard.SetTextAsync(enteredText);
```

but after pasting (as expected) it has no formatting anymore. How can I achieve this?
For example, if you copy paste this text created with (https://boldtext.io/) "", it will keep its formatting in any platform.

Iv'e tried to embedd a custom font (DroidSerif-BoldItalic.ttf)
Then adding it to the FontStyle of the control.

```
<Editor FontFamily="DroidSerif-BoldItalic" Text="Testing copy"/>
```

Font changes but cannot copy with formatting. Even if I do a manual select copy it doesn't work.

Any tips how can I do this?

Comment: There is no official API in xamarin.forms to support this, and if you want to implement it, you will probably need to customize it to RTE control's source code.

Comment: It's ok I can do the customizations but I'm kind of lost here, what am I supposed to do? Create a Unicode char map? 

Comment: I think this is more tedious, you can try to look at his source code, to see how it is implemented.Why don't you use RTE directly？

Comment: You mean the Synfusion RTE? It's so expensive for an individual to purchase.

Comment: That's sad.Maybe you could try to find some source codes about it.